# UIImagePickerController with timelapse/slowmo in iOS8

Tags: ios, uiimagepickercontroller, ios-camera

Can I add those features to a `UIImagePickerController` on iOS8?
In the camera app it seems like a native capability - but the question is do such an interface exist?

Answer (score 1):

No, UIImagePickerController doesn't give you the option to record video in Slo Mo, Timelapse or add filters. For that you would have to use a Custom Camera built using the AVFoundation framework.